# Grab content of Javascript from head tag

Tags: xpath

I need to grab specific content from this Javascript tag which is in the  section of an html doc:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var sbc = "<a href='http://www.test.com/Default.aspx' style='color:#e16a58;'>Home</a> / Men's Bikes";
</script>
```

Namely the 'Men's Bikes' text. Anyone know how I can do this?

I tried this which gets me all the tags:

```
/html/head/script[@type='text/javascript']
```

But not sure how I can narrow down to just that one - there are numerous tags in the .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you apply this xpath to your input XML:

```
/html/head/script[@type='text/javascript']/text()
```

we get

```
var sbc = " / Men's Bikes";
```

using `substring-after` and `substring-before` can manipulate further the wanted output text. e.g.

```
/html/head/script[@type='text/javascript']/substring-after(text()[last()], '/ ')
```

outputs:

```
Men's Bikes";
```

ultimately:

```
/html/head/script[@type='text/javascript']/substring-before(substring-after(text()[last()], '/ '), '";')
```

outputs

```
Men's Bikes
```

Comment: Can you add any explanation of this answer about why it will work? Small one liner answers without any context usually get deleted.

Comment: I have added `html` and `head` to your input by the way.